# How to create a subsite inside the subsite by using Powershell scripts?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, central-administration

I need to create a **Site collection** under that I need three subsites, For example, Demo, is site collection inside that I need to create **Departments**, Contact, etc. Then inside **department** subsite, I need to create three subsites for  ex **IT support, financial,HR,etc**. How can I achieve this Site structure by using **Powershell scripts**,I referred this link [PowerShell script to create hundreds of sub sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115841/powershell-script-to-create-hundreds-of-sub-sites), But I need more Reference for that? Please Suggest some idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this and it works fine ! This will do what you want to achieve.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq$null) {
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$SiteList = @("Department","Contact")
foreach($site in $SiteList){
New-SPWeb –url http://Demo/$site -name "$site" -Template STS#0 –AddToTopNav –UniquePermissions –UseParentTopNav

if($site -eq "Department"){
    $Departments = @("IT support","Financial","HR")

    foreach($Department in $Departments){
    New-SPWeb –url http://Demo/$site/$Department -name "$Department" -Template STS#0 –AddToTopNav –UniquePermissions –UseParentTopNav

    }
}

elseif($site -eq "Contact"){
    $Contacts = @("Contact1","Contact2","Contact3")

    foreach($contact in $Contacts){
    New-SPWeb –url http://Demo/$site/$contact -name "$contact" -Template STS#0 –AddToTopNav –UniquePermissions –UseParentTopNav
    }
}    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sam, How to choose a different template for the subsite?

Comment: Subsites are created only in site collection, Inside Department subsites no other subsites  created, Because it throws an error for template creation,"The term template is not Recognized"@sam

Comment: Hi Suriya the above code works fine just make sure there is no spaces in the code

Comment: ya sure let me check, shall we discuss in chat @Sam

Comment: HI @Suriya I have edited the code u just need to copy and paste it and run. It works fine.

Comment: @Suriya just make sure evrything is in one line and like this    and you are good to go                           New-SPWeb –url http://Demo/$site/$Department -name "$Department" -Template STS#0 –AddToTopNav –UniquePermissions –UseParentTopNav

Comment: Have you tried running it and if you achieve what you want to, then you should accept an answer :) @Suriya